# How can we scan C/C++ code using devenv in fortify?

Tags: cmd, fortify, devenv

I have been using devenv to scan C++ Code in fortify. For this scan, i have made use of solution file. But this solution file doesnt contain the entire source code to be scanned. So to include the whole source code of C++, is there any way to scan in fortify without the use of solution file. If yes, please mention here the command-line arguments to be used.

Comment: How do you compile the C++ code that is not in the solution file? IS the C++ code in a Visual Studio project file, such as .vcxproj?

Comment: The code that is not included in .sln file is compiled in visual studio